# Add div containing any iframe, wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I am using this function to make Youtube videos responsive. This adds a div surrounding Youtube embed codes.

```
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'custom_oembed_filter', 10, 4 ) ;

function custom_oembed_filter($html, $url, $attr, $post_ID) {
    $return = '<div class="video-container">'.$html.'</div>';
    return $return;
}
```

It works great, but I just copied it from someone's tutorial, so I don't understand exactly what it's doing. I want to modify it so that it also adds the same div surrounding a libsyn iframe.

This is what the Youtube iframe code looks like, and the function above adds an enveloping div as it should.

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/MKif3vEhgdg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" style="width: 690px; height: 388.125px;"></iframe>
```

This is the Libsyn iframe, and the current function does not add a div.

```
<iframe style="border: none;" src="//html5-player.libsyn.com/embed/episode/id/4016467/height/360/width/640/theme/standard/direction/no/autoplay/no/autonext/no/thumbnail/yes/preload/no/no_addthis/no/" width="640" height="360" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

How can I modify the function to add the same div to both iframes?

Comment: Did you see https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds? *"WordPress will only embed URLs matching an internal whitelist. This is for security purposes."*

Comment: How are you passing the iframe into the $html variable?

Comment: Hi George, thanks for the idea. The embed itself works fine. The Libsyn iframe works fine on the site, so I don't think it's related to that.

Comment: rpl, I'm not passing anything other than what you see there. I added that function to my functions.php file and it adds an enveloping div around youtube iframes.

Comment: Are the iframes being entered through the CMS or in the code? Because if they're in the code, you could just wrap that `<div class="video-container">` around the iframe

Comment: Alas, iframes are entered via the CMS by a non-tech end user. Believe me, I would much rather just have them enter the div themselves :)

Comment: Check my answer and see if the function I provided works. I can't test it out right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since libsyn is probably not a default oembed provider, you could try to register it using this code in your functions.php file:

```
function custom_oembed_provider() {
    wp_oembed_add_provider( '//html5-player.libsyn.com/*', '', false );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_oembed_provider' );
```

or you could use jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('iframe[src*="html5-player.libsyn.com"]').wrap('<div class="video-container" />');
});
```

otherwise, just use plain HTML:

```
<div class="video-container"><iframe style="border: none;" src="//html5-player.libsyn.com/embed/episode/id/4016467/height/360/width/640/theme/standard/direction/no/autoplay/no/autonext/no/thumbnail/yes/preload/no/no_addthis/no/" width="640" height="360" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: The first approach doesn't work. Didn't get to test the jQuery yet, as my host just started emergency security updates that have my site down. Will try that next, as soon as we're back up.

Comment: Have a look at this for reference on the adding an oembed provider: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer, because I went with Option 3, just wrapping it in a div in the html. Couldn't get it to use libsyn as a provider.

Answer (score 0):

The filter tag you are using `'embed_oembed_html'` only matches websites from a whitelist as mentioned here http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#In_A_Nutshell

This list contains youtube (so it works) but not libsyn.

You need to add support for libsyn by either calling `wp_oembed_add_provider()`  if it has oEmbed enabled ([docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider)), or `wp_embed_register_handler()` if not ([docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler)).